# MySQL Statement that reads data from multiple rows

Tags: mysql

I need to do a complicated mySQL query with just one mySql statement, i have a table like this where the data for each user is spread out over different rows

```
 ID  USER_ID FIELD_ID  VALUE
 1      1       2        my name is paul smith
 2      1       3        books
 3      1       4        loggedin
 4      1       5        busy
 5      1       6        lat
 6      1       7        lon
 7      2       2        my name is big boy
 8      2       3        pens
 9      2       4        offline
 10     2       5        idle
 11     2       6        lat
 12     2       7        lon
```

each row contains different data for the same user_id

```
 FIELD_ID=2 contains the user name
 FIELD_ID=3 contains what they bought
 FIELD_ID=4 logged in or offline
 FIELD_ID=5 is busy or idle
 FIELD_ID=6 is their latitude
 FIELD_ID=7 is their longitude
```

I need one MySQL statement that will return all users who are LOGGED IN and STATE is idle AND bought Books AND is closer than 5 miles for example.

So FOUR things have to be TRUE at the same time:

```
 1. user has to be LOGGED IN
 2. user has to be idle
 3. user has to have bought books
 4. user has to be within 5 miles of the office (located at lat=12.3, lon=13.3)
```

So i started off with this (does three of the four things above)

```
 SELECT distinct a.*
  FROM table a
   inner join table b on a.user_id = b.user_id and b.field_id = 5 and b.value='idle'
   inner join table c on a.user_id = c.user_id and c.field_id = 4 and c.value = 'loggedin'
   where a.field_id=3 and a.value='BOOK'
```

Im a total mysql novice, seems like the statement above creates three virtual tables and combines them to make the query, so i figure create two more virtual tables (one for lat and other for long), and combine that with my existing mySQL function calcDist(lat1,lon1,lat2,lon2) that calculates the distance between 2 gps points like this:

```
 SELECT distinct a.* 
  FROM table a
   inner join table b on a.user_id = b.user_id and b.field_id = 5 and b.value='idle'
   inner join table c on a.user_id = c.user_id and c.field_id = 4 and c.value = 'loggedin'
   inner join table d on a.user_id = d.user_id and d.field_id = 6
   inner join table e on a.user_id = e.user_id and e.field_id = 7
   where a.field_id=3 and a.value='BOOK' and calcDist(12.3,13.3,d.value,e.value)<5.0;
```

I added two lines (d and e) and modified the last line, the rest are the same.

Sorry im a real mysql novice and cant seem to figure out to compare values on different rows at the same time.

Does anybody knows if this is the right way to do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I have edited this, as strawberry wrote there needs to be something to aggregate on, which didnt work for your data. this solution below works. its quite similar to what you had previously done except it wrapped in a sub query. I've tested this and works

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT DISTINCT
x.USER_ID,
n.value as name,
b.VALUE as bought,
l.VALUE as logged,
s.VALUE as `status`,
lt.VALUE as lat,
ln.VALUE as lon

FROM testing x

LEFT JOIN testing n
ON x.USER_ID = n.USER_ID and n.FIELD_ID = 2

LEFT JOIN testing b
ON x.USER_ID = b.USER_ID and b.FIELD_ID = 3

LEFT JOIN testing l
ON x.USER_ID = l.USER_ID and l.FIELD_ID = 4

LEFT JOIN testing s
ON x.USER_ID = s.USER_ID and s.FIELD_ID = 5

LEFT JOIN testing lt
ON x.USER_ID = lt.USER_ID and lt.FIELD_ID = 6

LEFT JOIN testing ln
ON x.USER_ID = ln.USER_ID and ln.FIELD_ID = 7

)tbl

WHERE tbl.logged = 'loggedin'
AND tbl.status IN ('idle', 'busy')
AND tbl.bought = 'books'
AND calcDist(12.3,13.3, tbl.lat, tbl.lon) > 5
```

Your calcDist function should hopefully do something similar to this

```
AND (3959 * acos( cos( radians(12.3) ) 
      * cos( radians(x.LAT) ) 
      * cos( radians(x.LON) - radians(13.3)) + sin(radians(12.3))
      * sin( radians(x.LAT) ))) >= 5
```

Comment: wow, very nice!! i didnt know that could be done! Thanks much, i will try it!!

Comment: In the absence of any aggregating functions GROUP BY will return an indeterminate result, so either remove it or adopt the more conventional approach, and include a MAX on each CASE

Comment: Starwberry - thanks for the comment, would it be possible for you to write the SQL statement for what you mean, im not advanced enough to do it.